# How do I convert varargs to a single list even if the parameter is already a list?

Tags: groovy

I want a function that returns varargs as a list, such that

```
ensure_list(1, 2, 3)
```

returns

```
[1,2,3]
```

But the caveat is that I want

```
ensure_list([1, 2, 3])
```

to return the same value.

I tried

```
def ensure_list(Object... args) {
  if (args instanceof List<Object>) {
    return args
  } else {
    return Arrays.asList(args)
  }
}
```

but I get

```
[[1,2,3]]
```

The input is enclosed in a list by the time it becomes `args`. Is there a way around this, or some other pattern that accomplishes what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

args is always an array, your test for if args is a List will always be false:

```
def foo(Object ... args) {
    args.class.array // returns true
}
```

Instead check that the first element of args is a List:

```
def ensure_list(Object ... args) {
    if (args.length == 1 && args[0] instanceof List) {
        return args[0]
    }
    Arrays.asList(args)
}


groovy:000> ensure_list(1,2,3)
===> [1, 2, 3]
groovy:000> ensure_list([1,2,3])
===> [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider `flatten()` which would facilitate a mixture of lists and args (if that is indeed desired):

```
def ensure_list(Object... args) {
    args.flatten()
} 

assert [1,2,3] == ensure_list(1, 2, 3)
assert [1,2,3] == ensure_list([1, 2, 3])
assert [1,2,3] == ensure_list([1, 2] , 3)
```